# Encountered a strange inheritance problem in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, overriding

There are three classes: the parent class, the subclass, and the Main class

**Parent Class**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Parent : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected float m_hp = 2000;

    public virtual float GetBossHPFillAmount()
    {
        Debug.Log("Parent m_hp   "+m_hp);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Child Class**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Child : Parent
{
    void Update()
    {
        //GetBossHPFillAmount();
        m_hp--;
        Debug.Log("Child Update m_hp   "+m_hp);
    }

    public override float GetBossHPFillAmount()
    {
        Debug.Log("Child m_hp   "+m_hp);
        return m_hp;
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Parent m_parent;
  
    void Start()
    {
        m_parent = new Child();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        m_parent.GetBossHPFillAmount();
    }
}
```

The result of the output DebugLog is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IM1h.png)

What I want to ask is why does Child m_hp always print out a value of 2000, while m_hp in the same class keeps decreasing as I would like to see,thanks!

I want the output values in Child Update m_hp and Child m_hp to be the same and decreasing

Comment: *"the parent class, the subclass"*. The base class and the derived class.

Comment: Can you add your output as a text instead of image?

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `Child.Update`. Is that something that Unity does implicitly? I would assume that the output you're seeing is from at least two different objects. You could give each instance a random name/number and output that with the value to see whether it's the same object each time or not.

Comment: It should be due to two Child objects, one hanging in the game scene for update, and the other just coming out as new and not hanging in the game scene, so there was no execution of m_ Hp -- Operation

Comment: There must be log warning that Unity spews. You shouldn't use constructors for objects deriving from `UnityEngine.Object` (or it was for Components and SOs only). You should use Unity editor or `AddComponent <T>` to create those components.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Unity framework calls Update() method in every frame, as long as the class is attached to a game object: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Answer (score 2):

> `m_parent = new Child();`

Instead of creating an object of `Child` class like this, you have to attach it to a `GameObject` either in scene hierarchy manually or from the code like this..

```csharp
private Parent m_parent;
public GameObject ChildObject;

void Start()
{
    ChildObject ??= new();
    m_parent = ChildObject.AddComponent<Child>();
}
```

Here the `ChildObject` is a `GameObject` that have your `Child` script component attached to it in your scene. If your `Child` script component to be attached at runtime then you need to do it like this below..

```csharp
ChildObject ??= new();
m_parent = ChildObject.GetComponent<Child>();
```

---

##### Brief Explanation:

In unity classes inherited from `MonoBehaviour` acts as a `Component` and they are meant to be attached to a `GameObject` instead of being created as an object. So, always try to use `AddComponent<T>()` if you are creating and attaching it at runtime or use `GetComponent<T>()` if it is already present in scene and you are just trying to get it's reference.

When you are trying to create an object like this `new Child()` it is creating that separately which is not attached to anything in your scene. So, you are updating the `m_hp` variable of the `Child` component in the `Update` method that is in your scene and not the object that you had created.

For more in-depth understanding please refer to the documentation of [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)

Comment: before attaching the class to the gameobject it is needed to create it. The first line of Start() should be: ChildObject = new();

Comment: @HelderDaniel OP already had a GameObject in the scene with the Child script attached. Therefore I thought OP will reference it in the inspector. Thanks for the correction, I also added a null checking to it.